# PHP - Remove everything inside () in a string

Tags: php, string

I want to remove everything inside () in a string. For example if my string is `$string = "this is an example string (this is the part i want to remove)";`

I tried it with str_replace but naturally it just replaces "(" and not the content inside it. How can I do that since i won't know the contents beforehand?

Comment: Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: A little bit of research would help.

Answer (score 0):

this might work

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $String);
```

Comment: `[`, `.`, `(` and `)` have no special meaning inside a character class. They don't need to be escaped in this context.

Comment: *"Might work"*?  What use is that??

Comment: i didn't get want he wanted so i gave him on what i understand.

Comment: @Mynameisjeff What exactly didn't you unterstand?? lool

Comment: @MysteriousDoorknob your question isnt clear

Comment: @Mynameisjeff then learn English. "I want to remove everything inside () in a string", "I tried it with str_replace but naturally it just replaces "(" and not the content inside it." And i gave you even an example LOL

Comment: @MysteriousDoorknob okay mr english LOL

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "this is an example string (this is the part i want to remove)";
$string2=preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string);
```

Try this one